# C# class for a graph Node

Tags: c#, data-structures, graph

I tried creating a Binary tree assuming it will have max of 2 child nodes. But for a graph it will have one or more graph nodes connected to it. How can I create a simple class for a graph node like the below which I created for a tree. The reason for suggestion is because I am trying for a simple code to find all nodes info tied to a particular node.

```
class TreeNode
{
    public int value { get; set; }
    public TreeNode leftNode { get; set; }
    public TreeNode rightNode { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: With a List<TreeNode> ?

Comment: The value in this case is an array int[] value if the graph contains only y points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of *graph*, any node can have arbitrary many edges (neighbor nodes), so you have to use a *collection*, say `List<T>`:

```
// TValue - let's generalize 
// (e.g. you may want ot have double or string value associated with the node)
class GraphNode<TValue> {
    private List<GraphNode<TValue>> m_Connected = new List<GraphNode<TValue>>();

    public TValue value { get; set; }

    // get (and no set) - we don't want to assign the collection as whole
    // if we want to add/remove a neighbor we'll call Neighbors.Add, Neighbors.Remove
    public List<GraphNode<TValue>> Neighbors { 
      get {
        return m_Connected;
      }
    }
}
```